# SQLite "database schema has changed" error in Content Provider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I'm using `Content Providers` and `Sync Adapters` for my synchronization routine.

My routine receives a `JSONObject` and insert or update the entry.

In order to decide if we are going to update or insert we check if the entry exists in the database. This is where the sqlite error occurs.

```
06-03 10:58:21.239: INFO/Database(340): sqlite returned: error code = 17, msg = prepared statement aborts at 45: [SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id = ?) ORDER BY id]
```

I have done some research and found [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/1747) discussion about the subject. From this discussion I understand that `sqlite_exec()` has to be called. How would I implement this in a Content Provider?

**Edit**

Insert / Update check

```
// Update or Insert
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
/* put info from json into cv */
if(mContentResolver.update(ClientsProvider.CONTENT_URI, cv, null, null) == 0) {
    // add remote id of entry
    cv.put("rid", o.optInt("id"));
    mContentResolver.insert(ClientsProvider.CONTENT_URI, cv);
}
```

ContentProvider::update

```
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int count = 0;
    switch(uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    case CLIENTS:
        count = clientDB.update(TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
        break;
    case CLIENT_ID:
        count = clientDB.update(TABLE_NAME, values, ID + " = " + uri.getPathSegments().get(0) + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
        break;
    default:
        count = 0;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: do db.update ... if returns 0 then do db.insert anyway ...take a look at http://esilo.pl/ListSynSample.zip as i see you build smthing similar

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it does not solve the error. It now errors the same error but about the insert statement.

Comment: No, I'm using ContentProviders. I can imagine implementing the Transaction into the ContentProvider applyBatch(..) method but thats not an option for now because the result of a query is checked to decide if we need to fire another query.

Comment: in my sample i'm using direct db operations in both contentprovider and syncadapter. so syncadapter is not using contentprovider to insert/update data in db, it only tells contentprovider that data at some uri had have change

Comment: Why did you do it like this? Can't think of any reason to not use the Content Provider. (unless this solves error 17)

Comment: to omit contentprovider abstraction ... this sample is synchronization sample between android device and remote mssql server via MS SyncFx 4.0 ... on device update/insert using contentprovider in this implementation i'm setting changes made on device and than syncadapter sync this changes to remote db. if i'm downloading from server data all i need is just insert/update changes without setting them as "dirty" in device's db ...

Comment: anyway it's hard to tell what exaclly is causing this error without some part of your code ... so as i said before try to not open Cursor for checking if record exists ... if you have primery key update db with it... if there is no row with this pk it will return 0 (db.update not cp.update in cp implementation you can return null if underlaing db.update return 0 and check for null) ... then you should insert ... without having any Cursor(i'm asumming that you have 1 for checking if row is already in db) opened

Comment: Added the update/insert part to the question. The update function will return the amount of rows changed by the update query.

Comment: I get error 17 coming up for the very first (or sometimes second) SELECT * after dropping all tables and recreating data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved. I'm not sure why but after an emulator image wipe everything works exactly how its supposed to do. Thank you for your time Selvin!

Comment: "sqlite returned: error code = 17" is coming up for me when I do a "[SELECT * FROM mytable]". However, the SELECT command does return data. It seems like a false error message because it happens on the first or second "SELECT *" after I fill the SQLite DB with data.