# SQLiteDatabase warning Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Since I updated my sdk and eclipse I started to get warnings:

sqlite returned: error code = 17, msg = `prepared statement aborts at 21: [SELECT * FROM user]`

What does it means?

Answer (score 1):

as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226299/sqlite-database-schema-has-changed-error-in-content-provider) post, remove your database and create it again. hope it should solve.

Comment: it did not help. It not causing any problems, it just a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link about same problem... Check here may be it help you.. if it does not help can you please provide Your source code
[SQLite "database schema has changed" error in Content Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226299/sqlite-database-schema-has-changed-error-in-content-provider)